# How to input multiple learning data to model.fit() by tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow

I have problem when learning the data

I have 3-D sequential data

For example. `(1000,200,100)`

Assuming that each `(1,200,100)` is like the one sentence.

Each words becomes 100 vector and each sentence has 200 word, if there is not 200 words, then padding with 0.

In this case you want to guess the next word from past 3 words.

```
many_sentences= #the data of (1000,200,100)

input_len = 3
input_ = []
append_ = []
for sentence in many_sentences:
    for i in range(0, 200 - input_len):
        input_.append(sentence[i:i+input_len] )
        answer_.append(sentence[i+input_len] )
```

then I wan to use these like this, but....

```
 history = model.fit(input_, answer_, epochs=epoch, batch_size=10) # model is made by temsorflow.keras
```

I am bit confused here.

This `input_` `answer_` is only for one sentence.

How can I use the rest 999 sentences to learn?

Should I make `input_` `answer_` of each 1000 sentence and just appending?

or calling `model.fit()` 1000 times??

Comment: "This input_ answer_ is only for one sentence." What makes you think that?

Comment: @gionni yes I use `LSTM`

Comment: @Lescurel sorry it's not for one sentence,I am still confused.. but it just appending the every sentences `input_` and `target_`